# Why can imagemagick save out image previews but fpdf not save out pdf files to server side folders

Tags: php, imagemagick, fpdf

I tried the sample codes for imagemagick and it was able to save out document previews to the folder on the server.

I tried sample code for fpdf and it was able to render the PDF file fine when it is sent but fails when I ask it to save for directory.

Researching online it says the resolution to the fpdf issue is to set file permission to 777 (any source access permitted, as I understand). My default folder permission is 755.

I want to ask if anyone knows why I can save with imagemagick but not with fpdf.

The reason, I suspect, is because imagemagick calls requires exec() which is effectively command line access. As I understand it however, fpdf is just a PHP wrapper for PDF libraries already present on the server so should have the same availability to exec().

Haven't had a chance to go through the code of fpdf yet but as I am a noob to PHP I don't think that is going to be particularly enlightening.

Please help!

EDIT:
As requested

FPDF

```
$pdf->Output('testdocument.pdf', 'F');
```

http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

Imagmagick

```
exec('convert "docprev.pdf[0]" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 "document2.png"');
```

So those are the output commands of FPDF and Imagemagick respectively.

Comment: Show some code... one thing to check: are you specifying an actual filename for saving to disk? If you don't specify one for browser output, the browser will auto-pick one for you. Disk-based operations won't do that for you.

Comment: FPDF is not a wrapper for anything. It uses it's own code to generate PDF files and does not use exec() at all. Are you able to save files from PHP using `fopen`,`fwrite` and `fclose`?
BTW: Don't use FPDF - move to TCPDF

Comment: @Mchl: TCPDF seems newer and has better features but I recall finding someone did a benchmark on SO and found FPDF is faster than TCPDF. Also, I was looking into PDF readers and it said FPDI has fully supported integration with FPDF but not yet with TCPDF. Never heard of fopen, fwrite and fclose. I'll research and try it out.

Comment: I've been using FPDF for 4 years now and I really wish I could leave it behind and move to something more modern (especially since I need utf8 support) It's up to you of course, although I would recommend at least doing your own benchmark to see if your specific docs are generated faster on FPDF or TCPDF. Don't know anything about FPDI, so can't advise in that,

Comment: I recently worked on an online print solution combining TCPDF and FPDI very successfully. There are some limitations I recall related to backgrounds and z-index but the advantages of TCPDF far outweighed using FPDF.  I would recommend it to trial.